# How to make */* for many folders of self-contained cpp files?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I'm playing around some tutorial code from [this OpenCV 2 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/book). The code doesn't come with any Makefiles, and **I'd like to create a Makefile that can Make all of the files in the codebase**. My plan is to compile all the files with profiling, and then make a script that runs all the executables and collects the gprof results. Then, I can get some intuition for the computation time of various OpenCV functions.

The codebase is arranged like this: `tutorial_code/Chapter[1-10]/*.cpp`
Each `.cpp` file is self-sufficient and can be compiled without linking against other modules in this codebase. (There are a few small header-only libraries, though.)

Here are a couple things that I'm stuck up on:

- Typically, the `$(EXEC)` in a Makefile represents a file that is the culmination of much of the building effort. However, in my case, I want to create a separate `$(EXEC)` for each `.cpp` file. I think I'm close to getting this right, but so far my Makefile just generates `*.o` but not `*.out`
- I understand that `SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)` is a way to "collect" the set of cpp files in the current directory. It would make sense that `SOURCES = $(wildcard */*.cpp)` would drill down and grab all `.cpp` files in the subdirectories. It doesn't seem to work, though.

---

Starting from [this tutorial](http://www.puxan.com/Computers/Howto-write-generic-Makefiles), I set up a Makefile that implements the proposed functionality. It doesn't quite work... `$(wildcard */*.cpp)` doesn't seem to drill down into directories, and I'm not sure how to do something like `$<` and `$@` to refer to `basefilename.o` and to create `basefilename.out`.

```
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -w `pkg-config opencv --cflags`
LINK = g++
LINKOPTS = -pg `pkg-config opencv --libs`

SOURCES = $(wildcard */*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXEC = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.out)

%.out: %.o
    $(LINK) $< $(LINKOPTS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

---

- I'm fairly familiar with Makefiles and OpenCV, and I haven't had a problem compiling my own projects by hand-coding the lists of dependencies, objects, etc in Makefiles. However, for the matter at hand, it'd be fantastic to just automatically make everything without much user intervention.
- Feel free to comment, email, or message me for a copy of the codebase that I'm trying to compile.
- I've also thought of making a script that iterates through the `tutorial_code/Chapter[1-10]` directories and creates one Makefile for each directory. Then, I'd make an other function in the script to call Make once in each directory. The idea of doing one grand Makefile sounds like more fun, though.

---

EDIT: This **does** work if I use `SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)` and place the Makefile in the same directory where `cpp` files are located. However, I'm still trying to figure out how to have `$(wildcard */*.cpp)` drill down into subdirectories.

EDIT 2: The Makefile shown above now works properly. To see the earlier version, feel free to scroll through the edit history.

Comment: `$(wildcard */*.cpp)` works fine with me. Do you make in the right place? Make sure how many levels of subdirectories you need to drill down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a version of `wildcard` that works recursively to any depth using only `make` functions:

```
find-recursive = \
  $(wildcard $1/$2) \
  $(foreach f,$(wildcard $1/*/.),\
    $(call find-recursive,$(patsubst %/.,%,$f),$2))

SOURCES = $(call find-recursive,.,*.cpp)
```

Comment: Good idea! I'll give this a try too.